# Websphere RMI connection Issue

Tags: websphere, rmi

My development environment with 2 EJB RMI clients(different ips) connecting with same EJB Client Provider URL with IBMWebsphere 6.1 Application server.While I increasing requests from each client one client gives java.io.IOException: Mismatched serialization  issue.Websphere ORB listner Threadpool size is min- 10 max-50.What Can be the issue for this?

java.io.IOException: Mismatched serialization UIDs : Source (Rep. IDRMI:com.dfn.mtr.enums.ErrorCode:3762E1FD1A6B1BE5:601BEBFDABC9F5DC) = 601BEBFDABC9F5DC whereas Target (Rep. ID RMI:com.dfn.mtr.enums.ErrorCode:3762E1FD1A6B1BE5:CD1A966626885A23) = CD1A966626885A23
    at com.ibm.rmi.util.RepositoryId.useFullValueDescription(RepositoryId.java:727)
    at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.useFullValueDescription(IIOPInputStream.java:1288)
    at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.readSerializable(IIOPInputStream.java:1031)
    at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObjectInternal(IIOPInputStream.java:317)
    at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObjectLoop(IIOPInputStream.java:394)
    at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:348)
    at com.ibm.rmi.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:200)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:1897)

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly IBM's way of telling you the `serialVersionUID` values in `com.dfn.mtr.enums.ErrorCode` don't match between client and server, athough again as it is RMI/IIOP I don't see where serialVersionUIDs would come into it. Anyway clearly the .class files aren't identical.

Comment: Thankyou for your comments.But Why Some requests are working with both clients.is it depend on orb listener thread-pool?

Comment: @Kalla I don't know why you would ask that. I would be more interested in whether the same objects are always involved in the failures, and in making sure the same .class files are deployed to client and server..

Comment: same  class files using in both clients and server.Thats why i look in to more about thread pool.if it is use same objects then mismatch happen.is it possible?

Comment: @Kalla Once again, I have no idea why you think that a profitable line of enquiry. I don't. I suggest you double check about the class files. It is the most obvious cause of the problem.